# our site needs a route with route type detail-0pr. Update your file and try again

Tags: community, deployment, change-set

We are getting error **"Your site needs a route with route type detail-0pr. Update your file and try again."**
While we are deploying a community using change Set.

Please if any one can help on this issue. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Actually I am facing similar kind of issue while deploying community site. Can you please guide me what steps have you followed to deploy the community site @akshay

Answer (score 1):

Solved: adding Recommndation object in site